# Best way to get Context in android for long running non Activity Class?

Tags: android

As I see it I have two options:

1) Pass the activity context in the constructor:

```
public Method(Context context){
     mContext = context
}
```

2) Use a static Application Context that I can access from anywhere:

```
public class App extends Application{

private static Context mContext;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mContext = this;
}

public static Context getContext(){
    return mContext;
}
```

}

Which one do people think is best? Also does it make a difference if you are calling the non Activity class from a BroadCastReceiver, that lasts a long time?
ie -> MainActivity calls a Broadcast Receiver that logs GPS every 5 min, continuously. This Broadcast Receiver then calls the non-activity. In this scenario, could main Activity be garbage collected whilst the Broadcast Receiver keeps running, and thus if you pass context from Main, to BroadCast, and then to the non Activity Class, at some point hours, days or weeks in the future, might the non-Activity Class attempt to use the context, and find it has been garbage collected and is now Null?

Comment: This article about context is great https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/ give it a check

Comment: thanks @cutiko, always looking for good articles on Context, I find it the thing I have had the most trouble with :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the activity's context in that manner, it will not be garbage collected since there is a reference to it. That is the problem with passing the context of the activity. The activity might be a good candidate to be garbage collected, but it won't be because of that reference.

For that reason it is often preferred to pass the application context because you don't have to worry about memory efficiency since the application will be be alive regardless.

However, you may not need to make a static context to reference everywhere. Sometimes you will get a warning that this is not a good practice. From your activity you can call:

`getApplicationContext();`

and from a fragment you can call:

`this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();`.

Comment: In relation to a static context, I have an encryption class which encrypts everything I do in various parts of the app, usually called around midnight, right before everything is uploaded to AWS. In this scenario, should I make the context in my Encryption class static, so the dozen or so classes that are calling encryption all use the same context, or are you better off creating a mContext variable for each instantiation of the Encryption class? - I should add that the reason I seem to run into issues, is because my app is a logging app running in the background...the user never sees the UI

Comment: I don't think you should save a static context in it, I think it's fine if you just pass the context in each time. That way you avoid saving the application context unnecessarily. Some may disagree with this, however, and I'd like to hear their thoughts on it as well.